# Reimplement function in terms of existing function

Tags: node.js

Let's suppose I have this simple code:

```js
const a = {
  number: 2,
  method() {
    return this.number
  }
}


console.log(a.method()) // prints 2
```

Now I'd like to reimplement method in terms of method itself. Ideally:

```js
a.method = function() {
   return 40 + this.method() // should print 42, get a RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: If you redefine method and use it recursively, only your redefinition will be used, the function returning 2 doesn't exist anymore, and that's why you get an infinite loop, because `method` keeps calling itself.

Comment: But why would you do such a thing ?

Comment: I need to wrap an object's method returned by an external library, and I would like to use the same method's name so that I don't have to change existing code.

Comment: Well you can't override an object property and keeping the previous value at the same time.

Comment: You could maybe achieve something like this with the object propotype (assuming it has a constructor and it's not built upon a litteral object) and inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```js
const a = {
  number: 2,
  method() {
    return this.number
  }
}

// 1. Store old method
var oldMethod = a.method.bind(a)

// 2. Reference old method in new declaration
a.method = function() {
  return 40 + oldMethod()
}

console.log(a.method())
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) for more info on `.bind`.